# How to add another person to twitter api?

Tags: twitter

I am using a twitter api to post on accounts that sign up, and I cannot seem to find how i can add a new person. I want to add another person so my api can access their account, and get their access tokens.

Comment: "To perform actions on behalf of another user, you'll need to obtain their access tokens. Access tokens specify the Twitter account the request is made on behalf of, so for you to obtain these they will need to first grant you access. These tokens do not expire but can be revoked by the user at any time", [link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens)

Comment: I have looked at that page, but most of the linked references go to a page saying they no longer exist

Comment: sorry for the late reply. 
Your account must be created as "Team developer account" not individual. [The link on FAQ](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-portal/faq)
**Why can't I see the "Team" option on my account drop-down?**
This means that you've applied as an individual account, as opposed to an organization account.  The difference is the ability to give additional users access to a shared dev environment.
**Can I change my individual account to an organization account?**
Changing an individual setup to a team setup is not possible today.